# How is Atom built natively on your OS?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, coffeescript, atom-editor

How is Atom (the text editor) being compiled natively on your OS when it is written in coffeescript?

The way I've known coffeescript / js to work thus far is you use these scripts completely within your browser.

But how is Atom being built / displaying / reacting to things within your OS?

edit: this is not a question on how to build atom, rather what dependency or technology is being used to build the coffeescript natively into a desktop app.

Comment: I believe it uses `electron` which uses `node.js` and `chromium`

Comment: The same way you run javascript on a webpage on different OSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom runs inside Electron, as mentioned by a commenter:

http://electron.atom.io/